# How can you connect two instances in Protege?

Tags: class, instance, ontology, protege

I am trying to do an ontology in Protege but there is something that is not clear to me. I have a class "Student" and another "Academic Profile". I created an instance of the "student" class named Anna but, how do I create another instance in "profile" and make them relate? Should I create and name the instance of the profile "AnnaProfile" and connect them by properties? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so we have something like:

```
Student, rdf:type, owl:Class
AcademicProfile, rdf:type, owl:Class

owl:NamedIndividual, Anna
Anna, rdf:type, Student
```

So the question is how are Students related to academic profiles? This is where your domain knowledge comes in, I'm just going to guess that an academic profile describes a Student for this example.

Under the Object Properties tab you can add a relation for `describedBy` and perhaps an inverse of it `describes`. You can add the appropriate domain and range. Then on your Individuals you'll be able to assert:

```
owl:NamedIndividual, AnnasProfile
AnnasProfile, rdf:type, AcademicProfile
AnnasProfile, describes, Anna
```

This `describes` Object Relation is what relates the individual `Anna` to the individual that is Anna's Academic Profile: `AnnasProfile`.